# Updating MySQL root password in workbench is not workring

Tags: mysql

I have tried.
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
It works fine at the terminal.

But when I tried the same command in Workbench 6.3 it fails to execute.
It displays the following error message:

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('donE') WHERE User='Winter' Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences

I have searched the internet but found nothing.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you mean "fails to execute"? Does it report an error - if so what. Or is there no error but the password remains unchanged.

Comment: UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('donE') WHERE User='Winter' 
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
 To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can either turn safe update mode off

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

or use a query that specifies the host in the where clause

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='username' AND Host='hostname';
```